# Left hand category menu in product view

Tags: magento

The Magento template, I am using has a left hand menu for categories, but this is not shown on product pages.
How can I use the existing category menu for the product pages?

Answer (score 0):

1st you need to set product page layout `2columns-left` then add category block in left side (`catalog.xm`). this is only possible if you are Magento developer and you know the layout xml file structure.